# Ethics of storing signatures

Tags: storage

I'm working on a piece of software that creates a contract and captures the client's signature via gif and applies it to the contract (and spits out a pdf). Now, we're storing the data from the contract but when it comes to the signature, I'm not sure if I should.

Store it:
Pros: If the pdf document is lost, I can reconstruct the document instantly and easily for whomever needs it (us or client). (checked with the lawyers, reconstructing the document from data is legal and applicable as long as no data is or has changed)

Cons: Although I will never do anything with the stored signature, I can't be certain that, if I ever leave the company, my coworkers or replacements will honor that.

Don't Store it:
Pros: Ethical high ground, there's no option for anyone now or in the future to use that image and do anything with it. It keeps everyone honest.

Cons: Now there is no way to reconstruct the original document if the pdf is lost - which is a good possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lawyers are the most important people to talk to in this case.
But I'd still say don't store it.
If necessary, I'd suggest storing the contract in a format from which you CANNOT extract the original GIF. Such as taking a png file for the whole document, or some other solution.

However, if you are storing the whole document with the signature embedded (and not extractable) then you have your ability to resend the signature, and you have no reason to store the unattached GIFs.

Ultimately, having the unattached GIFs is just providing an enormous opening to getting sued.

Storing them that way also opens you up to problems relating to 'pasting the wrong GIF' into a contract.

I would say that having the gif files in a way that does not EXPLICITLY bind them to the ONE contract they apply to is VERY dangerous.

**EDIT**

After reading your post again I would say that there isn't a point in storing the GIFs or the PDFs. You should have a hard copy somewhere of the signed document (and if you are losing hard copies of contracts, then there are SERIOUS organizational issues) and after that, you don't need the *signed* version anymore, you just need to know the terms of the contract. So as long as you can reconstruct the terms for reading over, then I don't see why you'd need the literal signature again. If you need to prove they signed it, go back to the hard copy.

Comment: Well the company is "going digital" and it plans that within x months they will be killing zero trees. As such, all documentation, including binding contracts are stored (and re-stored, and then backed up in 2 separate locations). As much as it might make more sense to keep a hard copy, it's also not my call.

Comment: Okay, well, consider the backup stored in two separate locations as your 'hard copy' in the sense that you don't store it locally nor should you. The signatures are something which you do not need on a regular basis, and so storing the entire contract set encrypted off-site is a good way to do it. But neither you, nor anyone who comes after you should be able to just 'snag' them.

Answer (score 8):

1. Talk to a lawyer.
2. If it's grey enough an area, I'd vote for don't-store-it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to keep the signature for anything else?  If not I'd store it only for as long as is required to produce the PDF, as there is no reason to keep it around.

In New Zealand the collection of personal data is governed by the Privacy Act and as such one of its requirements is the data is only stored for the length of time required for the reason the data was collected.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I'll find out about that in Canada when I talk to the lawyers again.

Answer (score 1):

The signature can still be extracted from the PDF. So whether you store the original GIF does not seem to make a difference, security wise.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for thought:

If it was an electronic signature, you would probably not be able/allowed to store it at all. You could store the signature+document (i.e. the crypto-signed hash of the initial document) and verify it with the public key, but to store a lot of client's private keys to be able to re-sign documents.

Imagine some one breaking in to the database and stealing those private keys (gifs or RSA/DSA keys). That store would be very useful/profitable to a criminal organization.

Do you want to expose yourself to that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, a GIF can be re-created by anybody with a copy of the document and a scanner...not storing you lose the benefit of having it, without any real security value being added....

Answer (score 0):

I would get legal advice on some text to place near the signature in the final document.   Maybe something like:

[John Hancock http://rightzinger.com/LibraryofProgress/FoundingFathers/John_Hancock_signature.gif](http://rightzinger.com/LibraryofProgress/FoundingFathers/John_Hancock_signature.gif)

*(electronically added signature)*